# EXC_BADINSTRUCTION when computing a hash value

Tags: swift

The following code will crash with an EXC_BADINSTRUCTION. Im trying to figure out what is the actual cause of the crash, or if there is a better way of computing a hashValue for a given struct.

```
struct Provider{
    let name = "AmazonPrime"
    let country = "us"
    let identifier = "us-AmazonPrime"
}

let provider = Provider()
//Crash on hashValue
let hashValue = (provider.name.hashValue + provider.country.hashValue + provider.identifier.hashValue)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swift language does not allow for math to overflow when using the basic arithmetic operators (as noted in the [Arithmetic Operators area of the Basic Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID60) section of The Swift Programming Guide).  If the 3 hash values you're adding exceed `Int.max` (`Hashable` declares the `hashValue` as an `Int`), you will receive that crash type.

If you want overflow, you have to use the overflow arithmetic operators, as defined in the [Overflow Operators area of the Basic Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID37) section of the Swift Programming Guide.

They are: `&+` `&-` and `&*`