# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION evaluating boolean comparisons

Tags: swift, swift2

I don't understand this crash in Swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (homeChosen == true && section > 0 && indexChosen + offset == section) {

EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTIONcode = EXC_1386_INVOP_subcode 0x0
```

on that first line in the method.

homechosen is defined as

```
var indexChosen = 0
var homeChosen:Bool! at the top of the class
```

Why is this crashing?

Isolated to :

```
                if (indexChosen + offset == section) {
```

Comparing if `an Int + Int == Int` is crashing.
indexChosen is 0.

Comment: What are the values and types of indexChosen and offset?

Comment: maybe `homeChosen` is nil

Comment: Yeah, wow. Booleans defautl to nil instead of false. Unintuitive.

Comment: There are no default values in Swift unless it is an optional type, in which case it defaults to nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error I would guess that the values indexChosen and/or offset are not what you expect, and the addition statement is causing rollover to occur.  You can verify this by removing the math from the if statement and checking to see if the crash happens in the math specifically:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let newIndex = indexChosen + offset
    if (homeChosen == true && section > 0 && newIndex == section) {
```

If the crash is occurring on the line with the addition, [see my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911999/exc-badinstruction-when-computing-a-hash-value/32913328#32913328).